# Naive Bayes Results not Generating in RapidMiner

Tags: naivebayes, rapidminer

I'm running a Naive Bayes process in RapidMiner on Fisher's Iris dataset.

My main process is as follows:

> Retrieve Iris, Set Role, Validation

The Validation subprocess is as follows:

> Training Set: Naive Bayes; Test Set: Apply Model, Performance

When I run the process, there are no results. I've never had such an issue before with RapidMiner and can't find anything on the issue when I Google it or search Stackoverflow.

Comment: What is the Set Role operator doing - it may be causing the problem.

Comment: The Set Role operator had 2 parameters as far as I could tell. Mine were set to "species" and "label."

Comment: I haven't tried running this specific process again, but I believe the issue was related to my settings in RapidMiner. But, if you spot any problems given the info I've provided here, please let me know. I appreciate the response!

Comment: Is the output of the X-validation operator connected to a process output?

Comment: Yes it was connected. The problem was related to my settings after all. Thanks for the answers!